# Using SpanButton or SpanLabel in a list breaks the scrolling upwards

Tags: codenameone

I see some very weird behavior from SpanButton/SpanLabels. In the below code, if you drag the list upwards (to scroll the list upwards), all the displayed elements will jump down to the bottom of the screen. This doesn't happen with normal Labels (eg. if you disable the line adding the SpanButton).

Dragging down works as you'd expect.

```
//to reproduce: compile the code, drag the screen upwards, and all the text will jump to the bottom of the screen
Form hi2 = new Form();
hi2.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
Container cont17 = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
cont17.setScrollableY(true);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Label l = new Label("Label " + i);
    cont17.add(l);
}
cont17.add(new SpanButton("SpanButton")); //disable this line and the scroll upwards behaves normally
hi2.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,cont17);
hi2.show();
```

Comment: This is running into a special case problem with the span button. Can you please file an issue with this description and link to this post at https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/ Thanks.The fact that it happens with `SpanLabel` but doesn't happen for `TextArea` is very interesting!

Comment: Thanks for confirming the issue. I created the issue here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2950